# How to delete execution in camunda workflow

Tags: workflow, execution, camunda

What we want to do is to remove the created jobs when one event is triggered.
We did this with:

```
wfManagementService.deleteJob(job.getId());
```

We found this can remove the jobs (Table: camunda.act_ru_job) successfully, but the related executions are still there in table camunda.act_ru_execution.

We tried to call `remove()` from `ExecutionEntity`:

```
Execution execution = wfRuntimeService.createExecutionQuery().executionId(executionId).singleResult();
((ExecutionEntity)execution).remove();
```

However, it will get NullPointerException on doing so.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.isExecutionTreePr        efetchEnabled(ExecutionEntity.java:810)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.ensureParentInitialized(ExecutionEntity.java:1057)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.remove(ExecutionEntity.java:1154)
```

Does anyone know how remove the runtime execution?

Thanks!

Comment: Cancel activity instance is provided in camunda version 7.3:
http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/javadoc/org/camunda/bpm/engine/runtime/ProcessInstanceModificationBuilder.html